# How can I achieve Fake Depth of field for a 2D Image Plane?

Tags: camera, image, 2d, blur, depth-of-field

Let's say I have an Image plane and a Camera looking at the plane from some angle (large or small). 
I want the middle part of the viewport of the camera to be in focus, the rest should be blurred, but the part of the image face away from the camera should be the most blurred.

[image]

[image]

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9RzuCWdBDY

I have tried with Empty as Focal point at the Image plane but the F-Stop makes it ether all blurry or too sharp for the sides of the viewport. I also tried moving the focal point very far, but this has an effect only if there are actual 3D elements in front, the Image plane isn't affected.
What I imagine:
[image]
At angle in perspective.
[image]
I will appreciate your suggestions. I'm looking to repeat the solution for other projects, so I hope what I need as camera blur is easy to achieve.

Comment: "but the part of the image face away from the camera should be the most blurred." - what are you talking about? Actually the whole question is unclear. You should edit it and describe what you want to do, maybe show an example of desired result.

Comment: Are you just asking how to render depth of field, or is there more to this question? What exactly do you want to do with the plane?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MartynasŽiemys like this After effects tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9RzuCWdBDY in perspective, closer it is the plane as angle to the camera the sharper the image is. Also the sides are out of focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using the Compositor, you can use a *Defocus* Node when you enable the Z Pass in the *View Layer Properties*:
[image]

For more control over the blur shape, you can also use the *Defocus* Node with a (blurred) *Box Mask* instead of the actual Z Pass, but this is only a 2D effect:

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I did tried the Defocus node, but I guess I was following the wrong tutorial.  Only left to feather out the Mask edges. Trying it with "Double Edge Mask".